# How I can remove\delete object in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I have class and two objects. I want to delete 1st object. How I can delete it?

I tried just delete() (I found it on kotlinlangcom) but it doesn't work. I have red light bulb what recommend: "Create member function Person.delete", "Rename reference" and "Create extension function Person.delete".

```
fun main() {
    // copy object in object
    data class Person (var name: String = "Orig", var type: String = "piece",
                       var age: Int = 18, var high: Double = 25.7, var code: Int = 1522)
    {
        var info: String = "0"
        get() = "Name: $name Age: $age Type: $type High: $high Code: $code"
    }
    val ann: Person = Person("Ann", "man", 10, 0.5, 1408) // 1st object with some properties
    var bob: Person = Person("Bob", "girl", 20, 15.0, 1239) // 2nd object without prop
    println(ann.info)// props 1st object
    println(bob.info)// props 2nd object
    print(" ---- ")
    bob = ann.copy() // copy 1st in 2nd
    println("Bob has Anns' props: ")
    print("final " + bob.info) // new props 2nd object
    bob.delete()

}
```

Comment: What is `delete` and where does it come from, or what it is supposed to do?

Comment: Are you trying to delete it from memory?

Comment: Kotlin handles the variable reference in memory, so developer does not have control on that. I guess `bob = null` is something you want (while `bob` is nullable).

Comment: Kotlin is not C++ where you have extended control over which object will get to live in memory. Kotlin works on JVM so that means that it comes with a garbage collector. Garbage collector automatically collects unused objects in the heap on a condition that they can not be reached anymore by any object(not counting weak/soft references).

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to thing about deleting objects like in other languages like c++/c ... the garbage collector of the JVM is taking care of it (if you use kotlin with jvm) 
All you need to know is keeping no references on the object

So if you have a collection (list,map ...) where you put the object in, you also have to put it out if the collection is a property of a long living class like a model or something ... thats the only possiblity to getting into trouble within kotlin, putting a reference into a collection which is referenced by a static or long living object.

Within a function there is no need to delete the objects created withing.
Keep in mind that the garbage collector (GC) is not running instantly after finishing the method. There are different strategies depending on the age of the object and the garbage collector itself. If you would like to see the GC in action, this tool (visualgc) https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/visualgc-136680.html has some pretty nice visualisations.

You could also find much more details about garbage collection here: https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/gc01/index.html

Comment: Thank you. I just tried to understand deepcopy and copy. If kotlin works on JVM, how I can deepcopy object or I dont need it? Or I can deepcopy not all things? I tried find information in Google but find nothing. Can you help me?